# Find the limit $(x(y-1)^2\cos x)/(x^2+2(y-1)^2)$ or show that it does not exist

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,1)}\frac{x(y-1)^2 \cos x}{x^2+2(y-1)^2}$$

I have tested it along a few different paths and believe that the limit is $0$. Is this right? And if so, how do I now proceed with the Epsilon-Delta definition of a limit?

Comment: First: that $\cos x$ approaches to $1$, so you can get rid of it. Second: change the variable $y-1= t \to 0$. Third: change everything into polar coordinates and see that everything is bounded by $\rho$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(y-1)\sqrt 2=u.$  For $(x,y)\ne (0,1)$ we have $$|(x(y-1)^2\cos x)/2(x^2+2(y-1)^2|=|(x u^2\cos x)/2(x^2+u^2)|\leq$$ $$\leq |x u^2/2(x^2+u^2)|= |x|\cdot u^2/2(x^2+u^2)\leq $$ $$\leq |x|\cdot (x^2+u^2)/2(x^2+u^2)=|x|/2.$$

Comment: The substitution $(y-1)\sqrt 2=u$ is merely to make it easier to see,  with fewer  visible details.